# How to properly use the "next-page-token" in Google Directory API

Tags: python, google-api

Following the example found here...

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-mobile-devices

I have tried to grab chromeos devices from an OU in the directory only to infinitely cycle through the first 100 devices knowing that I have 350+ devices in this OU. All I am able to pull is the first 100 devices and it loops forever.

I have verified that the "next-page-token" is always different for each excute call and is never "empty" or "none" or "null" etc.

```
import pickle
import os.path
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos.readonly']

def main():

## assume proper credentials at this poin in the aCreds variable

    aService = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=aCreds)
    aRequest = aService.chromeosdevices().list(customerId='my_customer', orderBy='serialNumber', projection='FULL', pageToken=None, maxResults=500, sortOrder=None, query=None, fields='nextPageToken,chromeosdevices(macAddress, serialNumber, status, orgUnitPath)', orgUnitPath='/1/1030/Devices')

    aPageToken = "init"

    while aPageToken :
        aResults = aRequest.execute()        
        aRequest.pageToken = aResults['nextPageToken']
        aPageToken = aResults['nextPageToken']

        if aResults:
           aString = str(aResults['chromeosdevices']).replace("'", "\"")
           aDevices = json.loads(aString)
           for aRow in aDevices :
             print(aRow["serialNumber"],aRow["macAddress"],aRow["orgUnitPath"])
             aCount = aCount+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So it will just repeatedly print out the first 100 devices as an example below

```
888LPN2 34415dee00e8 /1/1030/Devices.
```

I would expect that after 350 devices are printed the program would terminate but it will just go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

In this example the request object needs to be recreated each time so the loop changes a bit to something like this

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos.readonly']

def main():

## assume proper credentials at this poin in the aCreds variable

    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=aCreds)

## move request from here to inside of loop and change pagetoken for each creation

    aNextPageToken = "one"
    aPageToken = None

    while aNextPageToken :
        aRequest = service.chromeosdevices().list(customerId='my_customer', orderBy='serialNumber', projection='FULL', pageToken=aPageToken, maxResults=100, sortOrder=None, query=None, fields='nextPageToken,chromeosdevices(macAddress, serialNumber, status, orgUnitPath)', orgUnitPath='/1/1030/Devices')
        aResults = aRequest.execute() 
        aNextPageToken =  None
        if 'nextPageToken' in aResults :
           aPageToken = aResults['nextPageToken']
           aNextPageToken = aResults['nextPageToken']

        if aResults:            
           aString = str(aResults['chromeosdevices']).replace("'", "\"")
           aDevices = json.loads(aString)
           for aRow in aDevices :
             print(aRow["serialNumber"],aRow["macAddress"],aRow["orgUnitPath"])
             aCount = aCount+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```